# Creating WCF Rest Service to Find the Distance

Tags: wcf, rest, geolocation

I am trying to Build WCF Rest API to return the Distance between two Points.

To calculate a Distance I need source point's Latitude,Longitude and Destination point's

Latitude and Longitude.

Can anyone Guide me to the Articles or any sources related to distance Calculation using WCF Rest Architecture.

Thanks & Regards,

Vijay

Answer (score 0):

There are various formulas for calculating the distance between two latitude and longitude points. Each has it's advantages and disadvantages. Some of the available formulas are haversine, spherical law of cosines, equirectangular approximation, bearing, and midpoint. The following website describes each formula as well as gives javascript code for implementing each:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

As for retrieving the latitude and longitude of a location via a REST service, I recommend GeoNames. I use them for postal code validation but they also provide latitude and longitude information. They have both free and paid services.

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html